# 500 internal error on SVN commit with Yosemite

Tags: svn, osx-yosemite

I am using User-Friendly SVN on my CentOS 6.5 machine where reside my Qt project. In this machine there is svn 1.8.13.
Normally I use my PC with CentOS and QtCreator installed to checkout and commit the modification of my project. In this case all works properly.
Now I installed Qt5.4 on Yosemite with svn 1.7.19. The checkout works, but when I try to commit my modification a get the following error:

```
svn: E175002: Commit failed (details follow):
svn: E175002: Server sent unexpected return value (500 Internal Error) in response to POST request for '/usvn/svn/repos_name/!svn/me'
The command "/usr/bin/svn" terminated with exit code 1.
```

I tried to check the error_log file on the server side, but no error are generated.
I do not understand why with Qt creator on CentOS I'm able to commit my project and I cannot with Yosemite.
I hope that someone can help me solving this issue.

---

Hello to everybody I have updated about this problem.
The problem is still present but I think is not related to Yosemite because I tried to do the same thing using a CentOS 6.6 Virtual Machine.

On this virtual machine first used the svn version available (1.6.11) and all works fine during commit.
After that I tried updating svn to the 1.7 version and a got the same error during commit:

```
svn: E175002: Commit failed (details follow):
svn: E175002: Server sent unexpected return value (500 Internal Error) in response to POST request for '/usvn/svn/repos_name/!svn/me'
The command "/usr/bin/svn" terminated with exit code 1.
```

This a compatibility issue between different version of svn?
I want to remind that the svn server (CentOS 6.6) run the version 1.8.13

Can someone help me to solve this problem? I do not understand if it is a server configuration issue of not?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does it work from the commandline?

Comment: No, it doesn't work. I tried running from command line:    
<br>

    /usr/bin/svn commit --username myuser --password ******** --non-interactive --encoding utf8 --file list_of_file_to_commit

But I get the following message:
<br>

    svn: E205004: Log message file is a versioned file; use '--force-log' to override

I don't know what does it mean.

Comment: You need to learn how to use SVN, the `--file` arg when used in a commit specifies a file to be used as a log output file (http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.svn.html#svn.ref.svn.sw.file).  Your issue is not Qt related, so I'm removing the tag.

Comment: Sorry I made a mistake reporting the command, but I realized later I was not able to modify the comment.

Comment: I tried running from command line:
 /usr/bin/svn commit --username myuser --password ******** --non-interactive --encoding utf8 --file /path/for/log/ list_of_file_to_commit 
But I get the following message: 
svn: E175002: Commit failed (details follow):
svn: E175002: Server sent unexpected return value (500 Internal Error) in response to POST request for '/usvn/svn/repos_name/!svn/me'

This is the same error that I get running svn with QtCreator.

Comment: Is it possibile that the problem is related to a compatibility issue between the macos svn version and the svn version on Centos?